# How to find project appartenance of a given file (Visual C++)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++

I am messing with a very big solution in Visual C++ 2008 (150+ projects), and by browsing the code with the useful "Go to Definition/Declaration" feature, I end up in C files, but I don't know in which project they belong ...

So here's my question : Is there a way to know the projects referencing a given file in a visual C++ solution ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a "Track Active Item in Solution Explorer" option in Projects and Solutions. When you open a file it will be automatically selected in Solution Explorer and corresponding project will be expanded.

Comment: Thanks ... I forgot about this feature which i thought was annoying ... but it turned to be a life savior ;)

Comment: The same thing happened to me :)